# Sorting module subroutines alphabetically

Tags: perl

I would like to sort my module subroutines alphabetically (I have a lot of subroutines, and I think it will be easier to edit the file if the subroutines are ordered in the file). For example given `A.pm`:

```
package A;
use warnings;
use strict;

sub subA {
  print "A\n";
}

sub subC {
  print "C\n";
}
sub subB {
  print "B\n";
}

1;
```

I would like to run a `sortSub A.pm` the gives:

```
package A;
use warnings;
use strict;

sub subA {
  print "A\n";
}
sub subB {
  print "B\n";
}
sub subC {
  print "C\n";
}
1;
```

Is there any CPAN resource that can help with this task?

Comment: If some of your subs are calling other subs, then in some cases (if you're using prototypes, or calling subs without parentheses), the order in which they are defined can make a difference to how they're interpreted.

Comment: @tobyink Thanks for the comment. I am not using any prototypes. Why is calling subs without parenthesis a problem? Could you give an example?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Parentheses are optional if a subroutine is predeclared or imported. `perl -wE 'sub foo { say "foo"; } foo'` works, `perl -wE 'foo; sub foo { say "foo"; }'` doesn't.

Comment: `my $foo = bar baz();` could be interpreted as either `my $foo = bar(baz());` or `my $foo = "baz"->bar();` (i.e. indirect object syntax), depending on whether a sub called `bar` has been seen yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse and reformat Perl code, you should use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).

This is the same tool that [`Perl::Critic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic) and [`Perl::Tidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod) use to accomplish all of their feats.

In this case, I studied the code for [`PPI::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI::Dumper) to get a sense of how to navigate the Document Tree that `PPI` returns.

The following will parse source code and separate out sections containing subroutines and comments.  It will tie the comments, pod, and whitespace before a subroutine with it, and then it will sort all the neighboring subs by their names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;
use Data::Dump;

my $src = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Save Sub locations for later sorting
my @group = ();
my @subs  = ();

for my $i ( 0 .. $#{ $doc->{children} } ) {
    my $child = $doc->{children}[$i];

    my ( $subtype, $subname )
        = $child->isa('PPI::Statement::Sub')
        ? grep { $_->isa('PPI::Token::Word') } @{ $child->{children} }
        : ( '', '' );

    # Look for grouped subs, whitespace and comments.  Sort each group separately.
    my $is_related = ($subtype eq 'sub') || grep { $child->isa("PPI::Token::$_") } qw(Whitespace Comment Pod);

    # State change or end of stream
    if ( my $range = $is_related .. ( !$is_related || ( $i == $#{ $doc->{children} } ) ) ) {
        if ($is_related) {
            push @group, $child;

            if ( $subtype ) {
                push @subs, { name => "$subname", children => [@group] };
                @group = ();
            }
        }

        if ( $range =~ /E/ ) {
            @group = ();

            if (@subs) {
                # Sort and Flatten
                my @sorted = map { @{ $_->{children} } } sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} } @subs;

                # Assign back to document, and then reset group
                my $min_index = $i - $range + 1;
                @{ $doc->{children} }[ $min_index .. $min_index + $#sorted ] = @sorted;

                @subs = ();
            }
        }
    }
}

print $doc->serialize;

1;

__DATA__
package A;
use warnings;
use strict;

=comment
Pod describing subC
=cut
sub subC {
    print "C\n";
}

INIT {
    print "Hello World";
}

sub subB {
    print "B\n";
}

# Hello subA comment
sub subA {
    print "A\n";
}

1;
```

Output:

```
package A;
use warnings;
use strict;

=comment
Pod describing subC
=cut
sub subC {
    print "C\n";
}

INIT {
    print "Hello World";
}

# Hello subA comment
sub subA {
    print "A\n";
}

sub subB {
    print "B\n";
}

1;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I think this must be the most general and robust solution, and it also seems to work perfectly! I still have one small concern: How certain can we be certain, in general, that the sorted file represents the same Perl code as the original file? (The documentation for PPI says it is "Round Trip Safe", but that is for the case where you do not change the tree..).. Is there a way to programmatically test this assertion? (I had a look at `B::Deparse` but I am not sure if that is the right tool..)

Comment: (.. contd..) It could be critical, or at least annoying (if you still had the backup when you discovered the mistake), if the code got messed up somehow)

Comment: `PPI` is a very established module, so I do not expect any problems with it.  Additionally, I'm pretty confident with my code as well here.  However, as @tobyink pointed out, the order of subs can make a difference in how code is interpreted if you're using prototypes.  If you don't ever use those (which i don't), then you're probably fine.  And for additional safety, you could very easily implement this with $INPLACE_EDIT and backups.

Comment: I mostly coded this as a proof of concept, and not something that I expect to be used.  Most modules are not going to have so may subs that someone couldn't quickly copy and paste to sort.  If there are that many subs, then most likely it could use an architecture redesign, rather than sorting.

Comment: @Miller; This is a fantastic solution; thank you for showing me PPI.

Comment: @harvey I first learned about PPI on SO earlier this year, and have only used it for problems on here.  Nevertheless, if you ever find that you might have practical need for it, check out [my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1733163+%5Bperl%5D+PPI) for additional examples to get started.  Always happy to pass on a tool.

Comment: Note that this routine fails if the module contains specially named code blocks like `BEGIN`. In that case `@words` will only contain one item so `$words[1]` will not be defined..

Comment: You are correct.  I've updated the code to take into account BEGIN, INIT, END, etc. blocks.  It only sorts subs that are between those compile phase blocks as the order of those blocks should be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

First, here's my solution;

```
#!/bin/sh
TOKEN=sub

gsed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/__newline__/g' "$1" > "$1.out"
gsed -i "s/__newline__\\s*$TOKEN\W/\\nsub /g" "$1.out"
sort $1.out -o $1.out
gsed -i 's/__newline__/\n/g' $1.out
```

Usage: token_sort.sh myfile.pl

This is how it works;

- Replace all newlines with a placeholder, `__newline__`
- break out all `$TOKENS`, in this case subs, to their own line
- Sort the lines using unix sort
- Replace back all the newlines
- You should now have a sorted copy of your file in myfile.pl.out

A few caveats;

- Add a comment, "# Something", or "#!/usr/bin/env perl" to the top of the file; this will ensure that the header block remains sorted at the top.
- The sorted block will be the start of the current sub to the next sub - comments at above the sub will get sorted with the previous sub.
- You need to use gnu-sed for this to work, on a mac this means doing a "brew install gnu-sed"

Comment: Thanks, that was a clever trick! Note that `sub` can occur inside other subs or inside hashes. These subs should not be accounted for in the sorting.. For instance, writing `my $func=sub { print "Hello\n" };` gives a variable that references an anonymous subroutine.

Comment: What happens if sub occurs inside a string? For example `my $str="This is a sub cell";` ?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland; The short answer is my solution doesn't handle these very well. Miller provided an excellent solution for perl. Mine is less robust but can still be used as a general case in other programming languages or situations where a sorting block can be assigned by a generic token.