# How can I find all the methods that contain a specific string within a Perl codeset?

Tags: perl

I've been given a tricky task which is to write a log entry at certain points within a large million+ line code base.

The points that I need to log can be found from a list of 500+ template types. A template type is simply a string like "end_assignment_affiliate" or "interview_accepted".

I'm trying to work out how to write a perl script that will take the list of 500 templates and then search through the code to find the methods that make use of each specific template string (I then hope to use the list of methods to find all the entry points into the system for each template type).

So for example I may have

```
sub aSub {
 my($arg) = @_
 ...
 if ($template eq 'interview_accepted') {
 ...
}
```

I want to determine that method aSub contains interview_accepted.  interview_accepted may be contained within multiple subroutines.

It's quite easy to grep the code base for the message type and find the line number in files where that message exists, however I'm having a hard time trying to identify the containing method.

Clearly if I can do this programmatically it will be more robust, repeatable and much quicker.

Does anyone know of any modules or tricks that I can use to achieve this?

#### Update

I'm currently playing with using File::ReadBackwards to find the string, and then from that point find the first sub [name] { point.  I'm wondering though if there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Looks a fine solution, but what if it's not inside any function or method?

Comment: These strings don't make sense outside a method.  The real problem is efficiency.  I need to check each line of code against a hash of 500 odd keys.  I feel there must be a better way but I can't think of it...

Comment: Have a look at [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI). Here is an example for sorting subroutines alphabetically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501104/sorting-module-subroutines-alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My CPAN module [`Devel::Examine::Subs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) can do this with the `has()` method or function. Here's a sample script using the OO version, which will do what you want. Just enter the directory you want to search (recursively) as argument one, and the search term as argument two:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.18.0;

use Devel::Examine::Subs;
use File::Find;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new();

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my $search = $ARGV[1];

find({ wanted => \&check_subs, no_chdir => 1 }, 
       $dir,
);

sub check_subs {

    if (! -f or ! /(?:\.pm|\.pl)$/){
        return;
    } 

    my $file = "$File::Find::name";

    my @has = $des->has({file => $file, search => $search});

    return if ! @has;

    say "\n$file:" ;
    say "\t$_" for @has;
}
```

Called like this `perl des.pl business-isp/ template` results in this example output:

```
business-isp/lib/Business/ISP/Reports.pm:
    income_by_item
    renewal_notices

business-isp/lib/Business/ISP/GUI/Accounting.pm:
    _display_plan_stats
    process_renew
    display_add_plan
    email_invoice
    process_purchase
    display_payment_form
    client_delete
    _contact_info_table
    show_plan
    display_uledger
    add_plan

business-isp/lib/Business/ISP/GUI/Base.pm:
    start
    _header
    display_config
    _render_error
    _blank_header
    _footer
```

UPDATE: I've modified the script slightly so it can be used in a loop with a bunch of search terms. Just populate your template names into the `@searches` array, and specify the directory structure to search in `$dir`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.18.0;

use Devel::Examine::Subs;
use File::Find;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new();

my $dir = 'business-isp/';
my @searches = qw(template this that other);

for my $search (@searches){

    say "\n***** SEARCHING FOR: $search *****\n";

    find({ wanted => sub { check_subs($search) }, no_chdir => 1 }, 
           $dir
    );
}

sub check_subs {

    my $search = shift;

    if (! -f or ! /(?:\.pm|\.pl)$/){
        return;
    } 

    my $file = "$File::Find::name";

    my @has = $des->has({file => $file, search => $search});

    return if ! @has;

    say "\n$file:" ;
    say "\t$_" for @has;
}
```

UPDATE: Here's a script that uses the new `has()` method with the `lines` parameter set. It retrieves the entire line that the search hits, along with the line number it's on:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.18.0;

use Devel::Examine::Subs;
use File::Find;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new();

my $dir = 'business-isp/';
my @searches = qw(date);

for my $search (@searches){

    say "\n***** SEARCHING FOR: $search *****\n";

    find({ wanted => sub { check_subs($search) }, no_chdir => 1 }, 
           $dir
    );
}

sub check_subs {

    my $search = shift;

    if (! -f or ! /(?:\.pm|\.pl)$/){
        return;
    } 

    my $file = "$File::Find::name";


    my %subs = $des->has({file => $file, search => $search, lines => 1});

    return if not %subs;

    print "\n$file:\n\n";

    for my $sub (keys %subs){    

        print "$sub:\n";

        for my $line_info (@{$subs{$sub}}){
            while (my ($k, $v) = each (%$line_info)){ 
                print "\tLine num: $k, Line Data: $v\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
business-isp/lib/Business/ISP/Sanity.pm:

validate_data:
    Line num: 168, Line Data:  $self->validate_value({ 
audit:
    Line num: 72, Line Data:  my $date = $self->date({ get => $schedule }); 
    Line num: 77, Line Data:  # update the audit list if the process is claiming to be 
    Line num: 86, Line Data:  date => $self->date({ get => 'day' }), 
    Line num: 108, Line Data:  date => { -like => "$date%" }, 
    Line num: 123, Line Data:  my $executed_date = $executed->date; 
    Line num: 126, Line Data:  "Process $process has already run its $schedule cycle on $executed_date"; 
validate_renew:
    Line num: 304, Line Data:  $self->validate_value({ 
validate_value:
    Line num: 193, Line Data:  # return if validate_value is disabled! 
    Line num: 204, Line Data:  print "Sanity validate_value_debug: $tag, $value\n"; 

business-isp/lib/Business/ISP/GUI/Accounting.pm:

confirm_payment:
    Line num: 1312, Line Data:  my $date = $self->string_date(); 
    Line num: 1316, Line Data:  $self->pb_param( date => $date ); 
display_invoice:
    Line num: 1867, Line Data:  my $date = $invoice->[0]->{ date }; 
    Line num: 1928, Line Data:  $template->param( date => $date );
```

Comment: Awesome module, but it seems it does not use PPI internally for parsing? So it is not very robust yet, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll be working this week on making it much more robust, and giving it some new features (like in-memory module sub checking). Comments and ideas very, very welcome.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting a complete solution. Thx!  For a set of strings, this is printing the .pm and the method that contains a string in @search but not the string that was found - is that easy to do?

Comment: I'm working on this module today, so I'll see if I can incorporate that feature easily. I'll post back here shortly.

Comment: I'm just looking at the code - very nice - let me know if I can help?

Comment: I'm just about to upload to CPAN a new version with a module() method, some updated POD and new tests, then I'll have a look at returning the entire string found along with the subs it is in. If you have any comments on the code, I'm all ears. I want to collapse a lot of the work, as many of the subs do the same thing (call internal functions that do teh actual work)

Comment: Updated. Fetch v1.11 from CPAN when it's processed through the system, or download it from https://bitbucket.org/spek/devel-examine-subs/. The `has()` method now takes another param `lines => 1`. It'll then return a hash containing the line number and data that each search match is found on. I've updated my answer. The 2nd update has code that uses it, and output that can be expected.

Comment: Just got back - I'm checking it out and will feedback. thanks a bunch for this!

Comment: I think what I'm going to do next is make it regex compatible, look at integrating PPI into it, and then have it so you can inject code into subs. I've needed that functionality in the past anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the caller function.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html

```
perldoc -f caller
```

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = 'hello, world!';
print upper_case($text) . "\n";

sub upper_case {
    my ($str) = @_;

    #  0         1          2      3            4
    my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
    #  5          6          7            8       9         10
    $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
    = caller(0); # 0 = current scope, 1 = parent stack, 2 = 2-levels up, etc.

    warn "DEBUG: Called subroutine $subroutine with parameter '$str'\n";
    return join ' ', map {ucfirst} split /\s/, $str;
}
```

You can find the locations in your code that match the template strings using a regular expression or a code parser (like how perltidy works), as long as the strings are to be found in the code.

Code like

```
sub aSub {
    my($arg) = @_
    ...
    if ($template eq 'interview_accepted') {
    ...
}
```

will be easy to modify programatically for your entire code base, however
code like:

```
sub bSub {
    my($arg) = @_
    ...
    if ($template =~ m|interview_a\w+|)
    ...
    }
}
```

will be much more difficult.  If assertions are done using 'eval', then
no parsing solution will work.

Comment: I don't think this will work (if I'm understanding you). I'd have to insert a call to caller in every method in a huge code base, then still print the warning if the string is in the method.  I'll check out perltidy though, that could be very useful...

Comment: Yes, but you could write a small program to read through the files and insert the debug/logging/audit code whenever it encounters one of your template strings.  I have written such a program to introduce line-by-line profiling data on a code base without the overhead of running the full blown profiler (which slows down execution dramatically).