# Finding a string in a subroutine with perl PPI

Tags: perl

This question is loosely related to [How can I find all the methods that contain a specific string within a Perl codeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404586/how-can-i-find-all-the-methods-that-contain-a-specific-string-within-a-perl-code#31405900).

While working on that question, Hakon usefully suggested that I look at [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI).

PPI intrigued me and, as a learning exercise, I've been trying to use it to pass a file and within the file find methods that contain a specific string.

PPI is large and feature-rich and I'm stuck on the best way to search within a subroutine.  I'm stuck both in my understanding of the PDOM and also the best method for finding strings

So far I have:

```
#The file to parse
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

#Read in the entire file (they're not that large).
my $src = do { local $/; <$fh> };

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );
my $subs_ref = $doc->find( sub { $_[1]->isa('PPI::Statement::Sub') });

#Test I actually have the subs print their names...
my @sub_names = map { $_->name } @$subs_ref;
warn "@sub_names";

# This is where I get stuck.  Do I now use PPI::Find?
my $result = $subs_ref->find( \&wanted ); #What does wanted contain?

#I can see I now have PDOM objects created for individual subroutines within file   
my $sub = $subs_ref->[0];
warn "name is " . $sub->name;
warn Dumper $sub;
```

Using the above I can see that I have parsed the file and can access PDOM objects for each subroutine within file.

A sample of the PDOM object looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'children' => [
                                 bless( {
                                          'content' => 'sub'
                                        }, 'PPI::Token::Word' ),
                                 bless( {
                                          'content' => ' '
                                        }, 'PPI::Token::Whitespace' ),
                                 bless( {
                                          'content' => 'Welcome'
                                        }, 'PPI::Token::Word' ),
                                 bless( {
                                          'content' => ' '
                                        }, 'PPI::Token::Whitespace' ),
                                 bless( {
                                          'finish' => bless( {
                                                               'content' => '}'
                                                             }, 'PPI::Token::Structure' ),
                                          'start' => bless( {
                                                              'content' => '{'
                                                            }, 'PPI::Token::Structure' ),
                                          'children' => [
```

And I'm searching for strings which may be contained within double or single quotes. E.g:

```
bless( {
'separator' => '"',
'content' => '"signup/welcome_$user_type"'
}, 'PPI::Token::Quote::Double' ),
```

My question: 
What's the best approach for searching for "signup/welcome" within $subs_ref->[i]?  Do I use PPI::Find (and if yes, could you give me an example?) or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterate through all `PPI::Token::Quote::Double` for each subroutine using for example:

```
my @result = map {[ $_->name, $_->find( 'PPI::Token::Quote::Double' )] } @$subs_ref;

for my $elem (@result) {
    say $elem->[0];
    my $found = 0;
    for my $node ( @{$elem->[1]} ) {
        my $str = $node->content;
        $found = 1 if $str =~ "signup/welcome";
    }
    say "-->" . ($found ? "found" : "not found");
}
```

Comment: Hey Hakon, I started looking at this, but I felt it was less than optimal because the string could be in Quote::Double, Quote::Single or possibly something I don't know about.  Then I thought perhaps find is the way, then I stopped and asked :)

Comment: @mark I am not sure how to simplify this, but it is a good question anyway. Nice to learn about this feature of the PPI :)

Comment: PPI seems really useful, but I think it needs a cookbook of simple operations. I'll try and pull one together and share.